# How to perform escrow service for NFTs?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereumjs

I am a newbie in this space and am trying to create a web3 project. Is it possible to have an escrow smart contract that houses NFTs? If so, I would greatly appreciate some guidance on websites/tutorials to reference.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Start with looking at Solidity smart contract examples. There are ERC 721 templates that can be customized based on use case.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721